# Error with ZIP and ZINB Models upon subseting and factoring data

Tags: r

I am trying to run ZIP and ZINB models to try look at some of the factors which might help explain disease (orf) distribution within 8 geographical regions. The models works fine for some regions and not others. However upon factoring and running the model in R I get error message.

How can I solve this problem or would there be a model that might work better with the subset as the analysis will only make sense when it’s all uniform across all regions.

```
zinb3 = zeroinfl(Cases2012 ~ Precip+ Altitude +factor(Breed)+ factor(Farming.Practise)+factor(Lambing.Management)+ factor(Thistles)  ,data=orf3, dist="negbin",link="logit")
Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.99934e-24

Results after fitting zerotrunc & glm as suggested by @Achim Zeileis. How do i interprete zerotruc output given that no p values. Also how can I correct the error with glm?

    zerotrunc(Cases2012 ~ Flock2012+Stocking.Density2012+ Precip+ Altitude +factor(Breed)+ factor(Farming.Practise)+factor(Lambing.Management)+ factor(Thistles),data=orf1, subset = Cases2012> 0)

    Call:
    zerotrunc(formula = Cases2012 ~ Flock2012 + Stocking.Density2012 + Precip + Altitude + 
        factor(Breed) + factor(Farming.Practise) + factor(Lambing.Management) + factor(Thistles), 
        data = orf1, subset = Cases2012 > 0)

    Coefficients (truncated poisson with log link):
                    (Intercept)                    Flock2012         Stocking.Density2012  
                     14.1427130                   -0.0001318                   -0.0871504  
                         Precip                     Altitude               factor(Breed)2  
                     -0.1467075                   -0.0115919                   -3.2138767  
      factor(Farming.Practise)2  factor(Lambing.Management)2            factor(Thistles)3  
                      1.3699477                   -2.9790725                    2.0403543  
              factor(Thistles)4  
                      0.8685876  

    glm(factor(Cases2012 ~ 0) ~ Precip+ Altitude +factor(Breed)+ factor(Farming.Practise)+factor(Lambing.Management)+ factor(Thistles) +Flock2012+Stocking.Density2012 ,data=orf1, family = binomial)
    Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
      unique() applies only to vectors
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say exactly what is going on based on the information provided. However, I would suspect that the data in some regions does not allow to fit the model specified. For example, there might be some regions where certain factor levels (of Breed or Farming.Practise or Lambin.Management or Thristles) only have zero values (or only non-zero but that is less frequent in practice). Then the coefficient estimates often degenerate so that the associated zero-inflation probability goes to 1 and the count coefficient cannot be estimated.

It's typically easier to separate these effects by using the hurdle rather the zero-inflation model. Then the two parts of the model can also be fitted separately by `glm(factor(y > 0) ~ ..., ..., family = binomial)` and `zerotrunc(y ~ ..., ..., subset = y > 0)`. The latter function is essentially the same code as `pscl` uses but has been factored into a standalone function in the package [countreg](http://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=522) on R-Forge (not yet on CRAN).

Comment: Thanks@Achim Zeileis. The zerotrunc has run fine following your suggestions, however, the outcome only shows intercept and estimate without p values. Does this mean we just use the intercept and estimate values and how are the values interpreted. glm run with error - see details on the main post.

Comment: The p-values can be obtained as usual with the `summary` method. The `glm` did not work because I had a typo in my suggestion `factor(y > 0)` is needed for the binary zero hurdle.

Comment: Thanks@Achim Zeileis. How about choosing the best model between glm & zerotrunc? I have tried AIC test which runs but with this message:Warning message: In AIC.default(glm2, zip2) :
  models are not all fitted to the same number of observations. vuong & lrtest seem not to run

Comment: The two models are complementary not alternatives! The `hurdle()` model is a two-part model that often leads to similar fits compared to the `zeroinfl()` model but is somewhat easier to fit because both parts can be fitted separately. If you substitute `zeroinfl()` with `hurdle()` in your problematic subsets, I guess that the problems persist. But then you can split up your model and investigate both parts separately which might give you further insights. For an overview of the `hurdle()` model see `vignette("countreg", package = "pscl")`.

Comment: Thanks@ Achim Zeileis, my understanding then is that zerotrunc will be solving the zeroinfl part. How about ZINB model as I initially arrived to the use of the two models due to the fact that there weren't errors if I ignored the factoring bit. Given that zerotrunc does run without problems what is the alternative for ZINB so as to be able to compare which model fit the data better.